# Somehow every second element of my data gets deleted (I need to delete each element in loop)

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am writing a js script to create table and populate it with data. I want to limit presented data and decided to delete each array entry after I show insert it to dom.

The problem is that splice and shift methods delete every second element and I don't get it why.

This is the main responsible function.

```
// ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
const loadData = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (let j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            const tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
        }
        myBooks.splice(0, 1);
    }
};
loadData();
```

Result I get:

```
index   guid    isActive    balance age eyeColor    name    gender  company email
0   72bb2d7f-75f8-4cba-bb0e-0a0bab3a1fa2    true    $3,952.70   21  blue    Mckenzie Conway male    ENAUT   mckenzieconway@enaut.com
2   d0f4e37b-afbe-4970-b303-ba50cfaa02a0    false   $2,198.67   31  green   Susie Peters    female  JIMBIES susiepeters@jimbies.com
4   99d5ad37-44be-41a4-be57-dcb000fab1e3    false   $3,939.64   29  brown   Castillo Carney male    VORATAK castillocarney@voratak.com
6   5bae2fde-3c2f-4e82-8e96-7436022fd08a    true    $3,284.90   23  brown   Fran Bridges    female  NETERIA franbridges@neteria.com
8   a58bb110-4945-46b7-9d10-511ed79b4950    false   $3,612.44   32  green   Lambert Cobb    male    XOGGLE  lambertcobb@xoggle.com
10  8d0b1059-dabc-4e4c-8edf-a829370ed734    false   $2,702.12   30  brown   Ilene Waller    female  GOLOGY  ilenewaller@gology.com
12  1405dacd-57f6-49ad-9b13-49c2992e4bf5    false   $1,266.03   27  brown   Delacruz Talley male    XINWARE delacruztalley@xinware.com
14  a720a721-321a-4502-97b7-c44df194e977    true    $3,953.08   36  blue    Esmeralda Cabrera   female  TOURMANIA   esmeraldacabrera@tourmania.com
16  a9a8ab4b-9d2a-489e-bf1b-c6f9df61c3db    false   $2,725.77   28  blue    Annette Atkins  female  QUALITEX    annetteatkins@qualitex.com
18  a88bec10-0758-4c89-9905-109e8e64ffb8    true    $2,517.34   39  blue    Mandy Taylor    female  COMBOGEN    mandytaylor@combogen.com
20  fe01ae07-e730-49dc-9ab8-1dc7e3a1526a    false   $2,043.76   29  green   Luisa Schwartz  female  DOGTOWN luisaschwartz@dogtown.com
```

Result I expect:

```
index   guid    isActive    balance age eyeColor    name    gender  company email
0   72bb2d7f-75f8-4cba-bb0e-0a0bab3a1fa2    true    $3,952.70   21  blue    Mckenzie Conway male    ENAUT   mckenzieconway@enaut.com
1   5a93ace9-650b-44b7-ae3b-69eb4362f6f1    true    $1,557.97   24  blue    Sasha Lang  female  EARTHPLEX   sashalang@earthplex.com
2   d0f4e37b-afbe-4970-b303-ba50cfaa02a0    false   $2,198.67   31  green   Susie Peters    female  JIMBIES susiepeters@jimbies.com
3   63bc0cbc-a7b3-4109-a0ad-8e50b5c3d242    false   $3,065.41   25  blue    Chang Franco    male    TRASOLA changfranco@trasola.com
4   99d5ad37-44be-41a4-be57-dcb000fab1e3    false   $3,939.64   29  brown   Castillo Carney male    VORATAK castillocarney@voratak.com
5   47854f72-3867-417f-84b5-b7052ab76a15    false   $3,604.89   29  blue    Ewing Wood  male    VIXO    ewingwood@vixo.com
6   5bae2fde-3c2f-4e82-8e96-7436022fd08a    true    $3,284.90   23  brown   Fran Bridges    female  NETERIA franbridges@neteria.com
7   b33db55d-a093-4002-ab81-c9d99e27a92e    true    $1,551.63   26  brown   Lacy Gallagher  female  OHMNET  lacygallagher@ohmnet.com
8   a58bb110-4945-46b7-9d10-511ed79b4950    false   $3,612.44   32  green   Lambert Cobb    male    XOGGLE  lambertcobb@xoggle.com
9   99cfc79b-0795-4d07-862e-7405b5ffcf53    true    $3,388.09   27  green   Kaye Valencia   female  ZILLATIDE   kayevalencia@zillatide.com
10  8d0b1059-dabc-4e4c-8edf-a829370ed734    false   $2,702.12   30  brown   Ilene Waller    female  GOLOGY  ilenewaller@gology.com
```

Comment: _"The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by **removing or replacing existing elements** and/or adding new elements in place."_ - Why do you change the content of `myBooks`?

Comment: When you `splice` - the index changes. So, if you splice the element out at index `0` - the element at index `1` shifts to `0` - your loop then checks index `1`, effectively skipping the one shifted down. Solution: iterate starting at 20 down to 0.

Comment: You could splice out the data first and iterate over the spliced list.

Comment: Explanations are above, but simple solution is to configure your loop to start at the last item and count down to 0. That way no index shifting occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So After @tymeJV give me an idea I switch up function a bit and it works fine now :)

```
const loadData = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (let j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            const tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
        }
    }
    myBooks.splice(0, 20);
};
loadData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];`

to

`tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[0][col[j]];`

The `splice` removes your first element, so you always want to grab the "current" first element.

Comment: Your solution is good too. I wonder how to get the best performance in this case :)
I think mine because I use splice only once.

Comment: You'd have to give it a try and see. At this scale it would be almost impossible to tell the difference, but I suspect that deleting twenty elements in one go should be faster, though always accessing the first element should be faster than stepping through as yours does.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the array you loop on every iteration.
to prevent your problem you can:

1. Loop backward, then when you remove item from the array you will still work on the next item and it will be on place.
2. Remove from the counter i after splice so you will have i--, this will make sure you stay on the first row.
3. Remove the items after the loop.

Good Luck,

Answer (score 0):

Try this: since you are removing the first item of the array after each pass, you always need to be using the first item in the array `myBooks[0][col[j]]`

To remove the first item of an array, you can use the `.shift()` method.

```
// ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
const loadData = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (let j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            const tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[0][col[j]];
        }
        myBooks.shift();
    }
};
loadData();
```